# Getting max from a case class List of nodes, returning Scala Option[List]

Tags: scala

I have a case class Node that I have written, and create a list from it and I need to find the node that has maximum disk.
I wrote the below code, is there a better way of doing it? Also, in my actual production code, my "nodeList" variable will be not just `Option[List[Node]]` but `Future[Option[List[Node]]]`. I guess still the answer/code won't change much except for the fact that I will do a map/flatMap to go inside the future and do the same thing. 
If anyone has a better suggestion to write below code more Scala way, please share your thoughts.

```
scala> case class Node(disk: Integer, name: String)
```

defined class Node

```
scala> val nodeList = Option(List(Node(40, "node1"), Node(200, "node3"),Node(60, "node2")))
nodeList: Option[List[Node]] = Some(List(Node(40,node1), Node(200,node3), Node(60,node2)))

scala> val maxDisk = nodeList match {
| case None => println("List is empty"); None
| case Some(lst) => {
| Some(lst.max(Ordering.by((_:Node).disk)))
| }
| }`
maxDisk: Option[Node] = Some(Node(200,node3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the code you wrote, I'm not sure if you really should use `Optional[List[Node]]`. You seem to treat `None` as an empty `List`, and you don't check for the empty list in the `Some` case. You might want to see if just a plain `List[Node]` suits your use better (where `None` would become `Nil`, and `Some(lst)` is just `lst`, and the unused `Some(Nil)` case no longer exists to confuse anyone).

If you do keep `Optional[List[Node]]`, I'd do it like this:

```
nodeList
  .filterNot(_.isEmpty) // maxBy throws if the list is empty; check for it
  .map(_.maxBy(_.disk)) // maxBy looks nicer than max(Ordering.by)
```

If you switch to `List[Node]`, it's slightly uglier:

```
Some(nodeList)
  .filterNot(_.isEmpty) // We're using the filter utility of Option here,
  .map(_.maxBy(_.disk)) // so I wrap with Some to get access to filterNot.
```

Comment: thanks. I have 2 questions.
    1. If I use Option[List] as I am doing, is your answer considered a better practice? This is not to challenge your answer but to get a perspective as to if my solution is less functional or less desirable and why. For my own learning only

    2. The second approach you proposed, is better than Option type I  a using?

    3. In case of empty list, my sol will break?

Comment: 1: I suggest not using `Option[List]` simply because you aren't using all of it. If you need to tell `None` apart from `Some(Nil)`, then sure, use it. You should try to avoid using data types that are "too big" for your use (they have values that you don't use). 2: My second solution just shows you what the code would look like if you switched to `List[Node]`. It's not better or worse; the difference is totally about your answer to `Option[List]` vs `List`. 3: Yes, your original solution will break if you have a `Some(Nil)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with List pattern matching.

```
  case class Node(disk: Integer, name: String)
  val nodeList = Option(List(Node(40, "node1"), Node(200, "node3"),Node(60, "node2")))

  def findMaxValue(list: List[Node]): Option[Node] = list match {
    case Nil => None
    case List(x) => Some(x)
    case first :: second :: rest => if(first.disk > second.disk) findMaxValue(first::rest) else findMaxValue(second::rest)
  }

  val node:Option[Node] = findMaxValue(nodeList.getOrElse(Nil))
  println(node.get.disk)  //print 200
```